# Filtering against query parameters Django REST Framework, Many to Many

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, filtering, django-queryset

I'm trying to build some kind of API, but I need to filtering request against query parameters in the URL (http:// ... / ?arg1=foo1&arg2=foo2&...). In my model scheme, I used a many to many relationships. Here is some of my code:

---

my_app/models.py

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField
from django.db import models


class MyData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    values = JSONField()


class MyModel(models.Model):
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    data = models.ManyToManyField(MyData)
```

---

my_app/serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from my_app.models import MyModel, MyData


class MyDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyData
        fields = ('name', 'values',)


class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = MyDataSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('country', 'data',)
```

---

my_app/views.py

```
from rest_framework import generics
from my_app.serializers import MySerializer
from my_app.models import MyModel


class MyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        names = self.request.query_params.get('Simon', None)
        if names:
            queryset = queryset.filter(data__name__in=names.split(','))
        return queryset
```

and here are the responses

---

Response to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "country": "Spain",
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Mark",
                "values": {"A": "Hello, it's Wario"}
            },
            {
                "name": "Simon",
                "values": {"A": "Hello, it's Mario"}
            },
        ]
    },

    {
        "country": "Italy",
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Jake",
                "values": {"A": "Hello, it's Luigi"}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

---

Response to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/?name=Simon

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "country": "Spain",
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Mark",
                "values": {"A": "Hello, it's Wario"}
            },
            {
                "name": "Simon",
                "values": {"A": "Hello, it's Mario"}
            },
        ]
    }
]
```

---

#### But the response I wanna to obtain when I request ?name=Simon is:

---

Response to http://127.0.0.1:8000/hello/?name=Simon

```
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

[
    {
        "country": "Spain",
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Simon",
                "values": {"A": "Hello, it's Mario"}
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think we can do this with [Django Filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/index.html) package. To use this package you need to install it as any other python packages. `pip install django-filter` will do the same for you. Then you need to define a custom filter class anywhere in the project as down below,

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters
from my_app.models import MyModel

class MyFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    name = filters.CharFilter(name='data__name')

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', ]
```

Then you have to change your `views.py` slightly as below,

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters


class MyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MyModelSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MyFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyModel.objects.all()
```

**Note:** I think you can define and use any kind of filter using this awesome package my customizing the `filter class`

Answer (score 2):

Try to use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to filter related data:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

class MyView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MySerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        names = self.request.query_params.get('Simon', None)
        if names:
            queryset = queryset.filter(data__name__in=names.split(',')).prefetch_related(Prefetch('data', queryset=MyData.objects.filter(name__in=names.split(',')))
        return queryset
```

Also you can use `SerializerMethodField`:

```
class MyModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    data = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('country', 'data',)

    def get_data(self, obj):
        names = self.context['request'].query_params.get('Simon', None)
        data = MyData.objects.filter(name__in=names.split(','))
        data_serializer = MyDataSerializer(data, many=True)
        return data_serializer.data
```